# VBA: Is it possible to update the worksheet when a filter changes

Tags: excel, vba

I don't even know if it's possible to do this, but I thought I'd ask.  I have a fairly large worksheet of about 90 columns and a couple thousand lines all in a table.  The only filter that will ever be used is on column 1 and all of the values in column 1 are unique.

Is it possible to update the worksheet to unhide/hide columns that have no value when the filter changes?